# getting cannot convert from 'void' to Systen,Action when trying to make a task

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous

I'm currently having some issues when trying to create some asynchronous call to the following method

```
QueryList.ForEach(x =>{ Value.Add(new Results { Name = x.Name, QueryResult = sumo.Search(x.QueryString, From, To, "CST") })});});
```

i would like to be able to create a task with *sumo.Search(x.QueryString, From, To, "CST")*

I tried with:

```
QueryList.ForEach(x =>
            {
                var tasks = sumo.Search(x.QueryString, From, To, "CST");
                Task[] task = new Task[] { new Task(Value.Add(new Results { Name = x.Name, QueryResult = sumo.Search(x.QueryString, From, To, "CST") })} ;
            });
```

But i'm getting "cannot convert from 'void' to Systen,Action".

i'm just starting coding so i don't know how can i solve this issue. Thanks for the help!

Just for reference:

```
public class Results
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public JObject QueryResult { get; set; }
        }
public class Query
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string QueryString { get; set; }
    }
List<Program.Query> QueryList = ser.Deserialize<List<Program.Query>>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Queries.json"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
Task[] task = new Task[] { new Task(Value.Add(new Results { Name = x.Name, QueryResult = sumo.Search(x.QueryString, From, To, "CST") })} ;
```

When creating a new Task need to provide an **Action** in the constructor (or a Func if the task returns a value). Change your code so that you provide an Action delegate, you can either create the action using lambda expression:

```
Task[] task = new Task[] { new Task(()=> Value.Add(new Results { Name = x.Name, QueryResult = sumo.Search(x.QueryString, From, To, "CST") })} ;
```

This should do the trick

Comment: Unless you are creating a task scheduler you should never be calling `new Task` a `Task.Run` should be used instead.

Comment: Agree on that. I just added the minimum change so that its code compile